# To show $Y/\sim_Y \rightarrow X/\sim_X$ is not a homeomorphism onto its image

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces

$X = [0,1]$ and set $Y=\{1-\frac{1}{n}\ \vert\ n \in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}\}$; $\sim_X$ is the equivalence relation generated by $0 \sim 1$. I have to show that $Y/\sim_Y \rightarrow X/\sim_X$ is not a homeomorphism onto its image in $X/\sim_X$. $\sim_Y$ is the equivalence induced on $Y \subset X$ by $\sim_X$

I know the following facts:

$f:Y/\sim_Y \rightarrow X/\sim_X$ is continuous. So, I need to show $f$ is not an open map or a closed map onto it's image.

And clearly, $f(Y/\sim_Y)$ is closed, since $[1]=[0]\in f(Y/\sim_Y) \subset X/\sim_X$

How do I proceed forward?

Comment: $\mbox{}$ What is $f$ ?

Comment: It's this map $f:Y/\sim_Y \rightarrow X/\sim_X$

Comment: Take the open set $\{0,1/2\}\subset Y/\sim_Y$. Then its image is $\{0,1/2\}\subset X/\sim_X$. This set is not open in the image of $Y/\sim_Y$ because every neighborhood of $0=1$ in $X/\sim_X$ contains infinitely many points of $Y/\sim_Y$.

Comment: But what is this map? Identity?

Comment: @Adayah Yes, or rather inclusion.

Comment: Yes, induced by the inclusion map $Y \rightarrow X$

Comment: @Adayeh: its the map on the quotient spaces induced by the inclusion of $X$ in $Y$.

Comment: @totoro, can't I take $Y$ itself then? Isn't $Y$ also open? Since $Y = Y \cap (-1,1)$

Comment: @junkquill The image of $Y/\sim_Y$ is open in itself. That doesn't give you a contradiction.

Comment: But the image of $Y/\sim_Y$ is closed since it admits $[1]$ it's only limit point

Comment: I got what you mean, my bad

Comment: @junkquill Every space is a closed and open in itself. Again, that doesn't give you any contradiction with $f:Y\sim_Y\to f(Y/\sim_Y)$ being open.

Comment: @totoro why don't you type your comment as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $0$ is an isolated point of $Y/{\sim_Y}$ but is not an isolated point of $f(Y/{\sim_Y})$. Isolated points are mapped to isolated points under homeomorphisms (because a point $x$ is isolated iff $\{x\}$ is open and under a homeomorphism $h$, $\{h(x)\} = h(\{x\})$ is open if (and only if) $\{x\}$ is open).

Comment: $f[Y]$ doesn't make sense since $f : Y / {\sim_Y} \to X / {\sim_X}$.

Comment: I've fixed the answer. I was taking it for granted that as $\sim_Y$ is the identify relation on $Y$,  $Y$ and $Y/{\sim_Y}$ are effectively identical.

Comment: Ah! I see, I though discreteness of $Y$ would come into play, could you provide me with a hint on how to prove the perverseness of isolated points under homeomorphsim?

Comment: I think autocorrect has done something funny (or even perverse) to "preservedness" (i.e., preservation) in your comment. $\ddot{\smile}$. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Ah! My mistake!